# How to set rotation for seaborn FacetGrid and figure-level xtick labels

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataframe (df) looks like below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = {'Year': [2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2019, 2019, 2019],
        'Capacity': ['4,999 and under', '5,000-6,000', '6,100-7,000', '4,999 and under', '5,000-6,000', '6,100-7,000', '4,999 and under', '5,000-6,000', '6,100-7,000'],
        'Qty': [2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to generate subplots in a grid, one plot per year. Each plot has `x='Capacity'`, `y='Qty'`.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Year", col_wrap=3, height=4, aspect=1)
g.map(sns.barplot, "BTU_Rating", "qty")
```

How do I add xtick label as listed in `"Capacity"` column?

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Specify `g.set_xticklabels(rotation=x)`

### Updated Answer

- Per [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) is is now prefered to use use a figure-level functions
- Using [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot)
- `seaborn v0.11.0`

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

order = ['4,999 and under', '5,000-6,000', '6,100-7,000']
g = sns.catplot(data=df, col='Year', x='Capacity', y='Qty', order=order, kind='bar', col_wrap=3, height=4, aspect=1)
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
```

[image]

### Original Answer

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Year", col_wrap=3, height=4, aspect=1)

order = ['4,999 and under', '5,000-6,000', '6,100-7,000']
g.map(sns.barplot, "Capacity", "Qty", order=order)

g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
```

[image]