# How to make multiple plots with seaborn from a wide dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I'm currently learning about data visualization using seaborn, and I came across a problem that I couldn't find a solution to.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
```

So I have this data

| index | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | 0 | 4 | 7 | 3 | 7 | 0 | 6 | 6 |
| 1991 | 1 | 7 | 5 | 0 | 8 | 1 | 8 | 4 |
| 1992 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 9 | 1 | 7 | 2 |
| 1993 | 2 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 7 |
| 1994 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 8 | 1 | 6 | 3 |
| 1995 | 7 | 0 | 6 | 4 | 8 | 0 | 5 | 7 |
| 1996 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 6 | 1 | 7 | 4 |
| 1997 | 0 | 4 | 7 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 8 | 5 |
| 1998 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 7 | 1 |
| 1999 | 5 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 0 | 8 | 5 |
| 2000 | 3 | 8 | 5 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 6 | 3 |
| 2001 | 6 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 7 | 1 | 2 | 7 |

I want to make barplots/histplots with col1, col2 .. col8 as one column and 1990 values as one column so like
1990;

| col? | val |
| --- | --- |
| col1 | 0 |
| col2 | 4 |
| col3 | 7 |
| col4 | 3 |
| col5 | 7 |
| col6 | 0 |
| col7 | 6 |
| col8 | 6 |

and plot them for each year from 1990 to 2001.

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col=df.index.value_counts())
g.map(sns.histplot, df.columns)
```

This is the code  that I've written
I looked at facetgrid but could get it working for my case, any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Imports and Test DataFrame

- **Tested in `python 3.11.3`, `pandas 2.0.2`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# sample dataframe
data = {1990: {'col1': 0, 'col2': 4, 'col3': 7, 'col4': 3, 'col5': 7, 'col6': 0, 'col7': 6, 'col8': 6}, 1991: {'col1': 1, 'col2': 7, 'col3': 5, 'col4': 0, 'col5': 8, 'col6': 1, 'col7': 8, 'col8': 4}, 1992: {'col1': 0, 'col2': 5, 'col3': 0, 'col4': 1, 'col5': 9, 'col6': 1, 'col7': 7, 'col8': 2}, 1993: {'col1': 2, 'col2': 7, 'col3': 0, 'col4': 0, 'col5': 6, 'col6': 1, 'col7': 2, 'col8': 7}, 1994: {'col1': 4, 'col2': 1, 'col3': 5, 'col4': 5, 'col5': 8, 'col6': 1, 'col7': 6, 'col8': 3}, 1995: {'col1': 7, 'col2': 0, 'col3': 6, 'col4': 4, 'col5': 8, 'col6': 0, 'col7': 5, 'col8': 7}, 1996: {'col1': 5, 'col2': 1, 'col3': 1, 'col4': 4, 'col5': 6, 'col6': 1, 'col7': 7, 'col8': 4}, 1997: {'col1': 0, 'col2': 4, 'col3': 7, 'col4': 5, 'col5': 5, 'col6': 1, 'col7': 8, 'col8': 5}, 1998: {'col1': 1, 'col2': 3, 'col3': 7, 'col4': 0, 'col5': 7, 'col6': 0, 'col7': 7, 'col8': 1}, 1999: {'col1': 5, 'col2': 7, 'col3': 1, 'col4': 1, 'col5': 6, 'col6': 0, 'col7': 8, 'col8': 5}, 2000: {'col1': 3, 'col2': 8, 'col3': 5, 'col4': 0, 'col5': 3, 'col6': 0, 'col7': 6, 'col8': 3}, 2001: {'col1': 6, 'col2': 0, 'col3': 4, 'col4': 1, 'col5': 7, 'col6': 1, 'col7': 2, 'col8': 7}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')

# display(df.head())
      col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8
1990     0     4     7     3     7     0     6     6
1991     1     7     5     0     8     1     8     4
1992     0     5     0     1     9     1     7     2
1993     2     7     0     0     6     1     2     7
1994     4     1     5     5     8     1     6     3
```

### Plotting with `seaborn.catplot`

- The **correct** way to create a `barplot` [FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid) (per the documentation), is with [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) and `kind='bar'`.
- It is required to convert the dataframe from a wide to long form with [`pandas.DataFrame.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), and resetting the index to be a column.
- A `catplot` is a figure-level interface for drawing categorical plots onto a FacetGrid.

  - See [How to rotate xticklabels in a seaborn catplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63909351/7758804) or [How to set rotation for seaborn FacetGrid and figure-level xtick labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61601588/7758804)
  - `g.set(ylim=(0, 30))` can be used to change the y-axis limits.

```py
# convert the wide dataframe to a long format with melt
dfm = df.melt(ignore_index=False).reset_index(names=['Year'])

# display(dfm.head())
   Year variable  value
0  1990     col1      0
1  1991     col1      1
2  1992     col1      0
3  1993     col1      2
4  1994     col1      4

# plot with catplot and kind='bar'
g = sns.catplot(data=dfm, kind='bar', col='Year', col_wrap=4, x='variable', y='value', height=3)
```

[image]

### Plotting with `pandas.DataFrame.plot`

- While you have asked about `seaborn`, given the dataframe in the OP with all the years in the index, the easiest way to plot the data is transpose the dataframe with [`.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html), and then use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

  - Set `ylim=(0, 30)` if needed.

```py
# display(df.T.head())
      1990  1991  1992  1993  1994  1995  1996  1997  1998  1999  2000  2001
col1     0     1     0     2     4     7     5     0     1     5     3     6
col2     4     7     5     7     1     0     1     4     3     7     8     0
col3     7     5     0     0     5     6     1     7     7     1     5     4
col4     3     0     1     0     5     4     4     5     0     1     0     1
col5     7     8     9     6     8     8     6     5     7     6     3     7

# transpose and plot
axes = df.T.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, layout=[3, 4], figsize=(15, 7), legend=False, rot=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response, thank you so much, I'm still at the stage where I need to be explained everything, your post is more clear than anything I could even imagine. Once again thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

`melt` your dataframe first.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': {0: 1990, 1: 1991, 2: 1992, 3: 1993, 4: 1994, 5: 1995, 6: 1996, 7: 1997, 8: 1998, 9: 1999, 10: 2000, 11: 2001}, 'col1': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 4, 5: 7, 6: 5, 7: 0, 8: 1, 9: 5, 10: 3, 11: 6}, 'col2': {0: 4, 1: 7, 2: 5, 3: 7, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 7, 10: 8, 11: 0}, 'col3': {0: 7, 1: 5, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 1, 7: 7, 8: 7, 9: 1, 10: 5, 11: 4}, 'col4': {0: 3, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 5, 5: 4, 6: 4, 7: 5, 8: 0, 9: 1, 10: 0, 11: 1}, 'col5': {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 9, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 8, 6: 6, 7: 5, 8: 7, 9: 6, 10: 3, 11: 7}, 'col6': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 1}, 'col7': {0: 6, 1: 8, 2: 7, 3: 2, 4: 6, 5: 5, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 7, 9: 8, 10: 6, 11: 2}, 'col8': {0: 6, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 7, 4: 3, 5: 7, 6: 4, 7: 5, 8: 1, 9: 5, 10: 3, 11: 7}})
df2 = df.melt(id_vars='index')

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df2, col='index', col_wrap=4)
g.map(sns.barplot, 'variable', 'value', order=df2['variable'].unique())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: hey @Brendan this worked thanks a lot, but can you tell me how exactly which variable is doing what, especially ```'variable'``` and ```'value'```.  I tried ```degrees = 90
plt.xticks(rotation=degrees)``` but it only worked for the last graph. Thx in advance

Comment: @nasc `'variable'` and `'value'` are the default names from `melt`; you should likely rename them to something more sensible.

Comment: I did try something like that but got keyerror, is there a different way to change the names